# Rollup/Svelte is not producing chunkfiles for dynamic imports. How to make Components to lazy loadable chunks?

Tags: lazy-loading, svelte, rollup, rollupjs, svelte-component

I want to lazy load some components in svelte.
No Svelte-kit, just in pure svelte.

I want to dynamically import a Svelte-Component and use it when required:

```js
const About = () => import("../Pages/About.svelte");
```

The import works. The component displays.
But there is no lazy loading or chunk files generated on build nor will there be any lazy fetched requests for the component.

Everything gets bundled in the main.js instead of beeing splitted accordingly.

here is my Rollup config:

```js
export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'esm', // added this to allow modules
        name: 'app',
        dir: 'public/build/',
        inlineDynamicImports: true, //Added this to allow dynamic imports
        chunkFileNames: '[name].[hash].js' // though this would help
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production }),
            compilerOptions: {
                // have routing and need hydration maybe this is a issue with chunking?
                hydratable: true,
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
        scss({
            failOnError: true,
            include: ['src/**/*.css', 'src/**/*.scss', 'src/**/*.sass'],
        }),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs({

        }),
        // I use typescript mabye this could be an issue?
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production,
            include: ['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.js'],
        }),
        copy({
            targets: [
                { src: 'public/index.html', dest: 'public', rename: '200.html' }
            ]
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

Did I miss something in my config?
Or how should I set up Svelte component code splitting/lazy loaded components ?

EDIT: This is how my build directory looks like after running build

[image: after build directory]

As you can see, there is no chunks. Only one main.js.

Answer (score 2):

By setting the [inlineDynamicImports](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputinlinedynamicimports) option to true, you are telling Rollup to inline the dynamic import into the single output file *instead of* creating separate chunks. Removing that option should cause Rollup to create separate chunks for dynamic imports instead (the default behavior).

Rollup should support dynamic imports by default, so you didn't need to set that option to allow them.

Comment: but inlineDynamicImports will produce side effect in advance

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the inline imports acually...

It sounds wierd:
But my config now looks like this:

```js
export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'esm',
        name: 'app',
        dir: 'public/build/',
        // inlineDynamicImports: true, <- removed this
        chunkFileNames: '[name].chunk.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production }),
            compilerOptions: {
                // have routing and need hydration maybe this is a issue with chunking?
                hydratable: true,
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
        scss({
            failOnError: true,
            include: ['src/**/*.css', 'src/**/*.scss', 'src/**/*.sass'],
        }),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs({

        }),
        // I use typescript mabye this could be an issue?
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production,
            include: ['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.js'],
        }),
        copy({
            targets: [
                { src: 'public/index.html', dest: 'public', rename: '200.html' }
            ]
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

the result is:
[image]